# How to type a hooks return value for cases of varying arity & return values (React/TS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, publish-subscribe

For fun and a bit of a challenge, I'm trying to extend on a pattern I saw for a simple state manager that uses refs to store state and a pub/sub method to update subscribers.

The original implementation only allowed the hook to be passed a selector function that would return a slice of the state - I'm stuck on a way to type the function that it can properly infer whether it returns an entire state object if no selector is passed, or just the state when it is:

[Here is a working link (codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/performant-context-hr2wfv?file=/src/store.tsx)

and the relevant code:

```
function createStore<Store>(initialState: Store) {
  const useStoreData = () => {
    const store = useRef<Store>(initialState);
    const subscribers = useRef(new Set<() => void>());
    const get = () => store.current;
    const set = (value: Partial<Store>) => {
      store.current = { ...store.current, ...value };
      subscribers.current.forEach((cb) => cb));
    }

    const subscribe = (callback: () => void) => {
      subscribers.current.add(callback);
      return () => subscribers.current.delete(callback);
    }

    return { get, set, subscribe };
  }

  const StoreContext = createContext<ReturnType<typeof useStoreData> | null>(null);

  function Provider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
      <StoreContext.Provider value={useStoreData()}>
        {children}
      </StoreContext.Provider>
    );
  }

  function useStore<SelectorOutput>(
    selector: (store: Store) => SelectorOutput
  ): [SelectorOutput, (value: Store) => void] {
    const store = useContext(StoreContext);
    if (!store) {
      throw new Error("Store not found");
    }

    const [state, setState] = useState(selector(store.get()));
    useEffect(() => {
      return store.subscribe(() => setState(selector(store.get())));
    }, [store]);

    return [state, store.set];
  }

  return {
    Provider,
    useStore
  };
}

const { Provider, useStore } = createStore({ first: '', last: '' })
function DisplayValue() {
  const [first] = useStore((state) => state.first);
}
```

I've omitted parts like wrapping the App in the Provider etc, but all the above works fine - however if I want to do something such as:

```
function DisplayAll() {
  const [state] = useStore() // { first: string, last: string }
}
```

I can't work out how to properly type this out. Can anyone point out some tips?

Comment: This is quite hard to understand - also there are multiple "store" files. Which one is the problematic one? What are your expectations? We're only given `useStore() // { first: string; last: string }`.

Comment: @caTS Apologies - thought I linked an isolated version. The main file is store.tsx, and the usage in App.tsx - I'm expecting to be able to return the full state and optionally supply a selector to retrieve a slice. I'm having issues setting up the optional selector, and typing the return of useStore to account for either returning the Store OR the SelectorOutput